# Parametrization of continuous paths

Tags: complex-analysis, circles, parametrization

> Given is the following chain $\Gamma=\alpha +\beta+\gamma+\delta$: [image: {}]
>
> $\gamma$ is a half circle around $z_0=4$. Parametrize this paths $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta : [0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$.

I'm not sure how to do this. For $\beta$ one can say it's a constant path, so $$\beta = 2 = 2\cdot e^{2\pi \mathrm{i}t}$$ For $\delta$ I'd say: $$\delta=-2t+2 \, t\in [0,2]$$ and for $$\alpha = \frac{1}{6}t+\frac{1}{3}, \, t\in [-2, 10]$$

For a circle one can write $D_r(z_0)=r\cdot e^{\mathrm{i}t}+z_0$. So I get for a full circle in this situation: $$D_r(4)=r\cdot e^{\mathrm{i}t}+4$$ Unfortunately I don't if these things are correct, especially the half circle. Any hints?

Comment: The Pythagorean Theorem shows $r=\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: The half circle is given by $D_r(4)=re^{i(π/4−t)}$ for $0\leq t\leq \pi$

Comment: @Fakemistake Why $\frac{\pi}{4}$? Sorry for this questions, but seriously I don't get it. A half circle can be parametrize with $e^{\pi i t}$, or?

Comment: It's because the circel starts in beetween 0 and $\pi/2$, right? And $-t$ in fact it's a half circle?

Comment: The angle between the straight line through $(4,0)$ and $(6,2)$ relative to the $x$-axis is 45 degrees, that's $\pi/4$. If you put $t=0$ in the parametrization, you get the start point of the half circle. The $-$ sign stands for a clockwise parametrization, as given in the picture. Oh i see a little mistake in the given formula for the half circle: It is correctly $D_r(4)=re^{i(\pi/4-t)}+4$

Comment: A full circle needs $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, so $0\leq t\leq \pi$ for an half circle. Where did you get the $\pi/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only straight line segments from $z_0$ to $z_1$:

$$
z(t)=(1-t)z_0 + t z_1 \quad t \in [0,1]
$$

and the arc of a circle with centre $z_0$ and radius $r$:
$$
z(t)=z_0 + r ( \cos t + i \sin t), \quad t \in [t_1, t_2]
$$
$t_1$ is the initial point of the arc, $t_2$ is the final point, traversed counter-clockwise ( use $-i$  for clockwise traversal. )

You will have to think about the parameter $t$ if you want $t \in [0,1]$ for the collection of paths.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you! Do I have to ’shrink' the paths by multiplying a factor?

Comment: sometimes you need $z(t)=z_0+r(\cos t-i\sin t)$

Comment: @Fakemistake I'm not sure if you understand my question correctly. For the circle I have to move this to 0 but what I have to do with the straight lines?

Comment: @jacmeird Your question suggests you can take $t \in [0,1]$ along each individual path. For completeness if you want to reparameterize $[0,1] \to [s_1, s_2]$ then try $(s_2-s_1)t+s_1$

Comment: Okay, so from Intervall $[s_1,s_2]$ to $[0,1]$ I get: $\frac{1}{s_2-s_1}t+\frac{1}{s_1}$.

Comment: @jacmeird  I think you are ok with $t \in [0,1]$ but you need to be sure. A concrete example, for $\delta$, using the recipe supplied in the answer, $z(t)=(1-t)(2-2i)+t(2i) \quad t \in [0,1]$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: @jacmeird $z(t)=z_0+r(\cos t- i\sin t)$ is clockwise, $z(t)=z_0+r(\cos t+ i\sin t)$ is counter-clockwise, and the picture shows a clockwise $\gamma$.

Comment: @Fakemistake correct and that is helpful. I updated the answer to include this.